# Blank Screen after logged in (only desktop wallpaper showing)

Tags: 14.04, system-settings

When I logged in to my Ubuntu, it shows blank screen (showing only desktop wallpaper, not black screen). I tried to open terminal from Ctrl+Alt+T but it does not work. The issue seems like when I kill explorer.exe process while using Windows.

Note: I just installed Ubuntu today with clean install from bootable usb and formatted everything in my hdd.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you have an AMD card, the clean install of 14.04.2 LTS has/had a bug where fglrx wouldn't play nice.

The fix I was told to do was download and use the clean install for [14.04](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/) (not point release 2) and then update as needed.

Comment: AMD Card mean what? a mainboard or a graphic card? I use intel for mainboard and AMD for a graphic card.

Comment: AMD graphics card to me suggests that my answer should help you. If you are up for it, try doing a clean install from the webpage I linked [above](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/) and see if you have any further luck.

Comment: I have read on another topic. They said that I need to install my drivers for graphic card before do anything else, Can I? because I am run out of bootable device to write the new iso anymore or else I have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: Everything is very vague at the moment, so it's hard to give you a specific answer. I've given a response based on a similar situation that had happened to me, but other than that I can't help you at this time. By the way, why can't you write over your bootable USB drive?

Comment: Did you fix this with the way I suggested?

Comment: I didn't try. But after I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and then I installed AMD Driver before getting any updates. It's work!